# Openssl package for MIPS 32 cross compilation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: openssl, cross-compilation, cpu-architecture

Am cross compiling my code in X86 machine and OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Earlier when i was cross compiling for ARM, it was working fine and my code was like below:

```
echo "### Seting ARM architecture in 'dpkg' & Installing all dependent packages ###"
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -y openssl:armhf curl:armhf libssl-dev:armhf
```

Now am cross compiling for MIPS 32 architecture same with below code but getting build errors.

```
echo "### Seting ARM architecture in 'dpkg' & Installing all dependent packages ###"
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -y openssl:mips32 curl:mips32 libssl-dev:mips32
```

How to download these openssl, curl pkgs for MIPS32? Ubuntu apt doesnt have support for MIPS 32 ? In Ubunut packges site also, there is not MIPS. How to get these pkgs for mips32?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What computer architectures are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10811/what-computer-architectures-are-available)

Comment: You'll have to pretty much build everything from scratch for MIPS. Or use Debian, which does have some support for MIPS.

Comment: I saw debian pkgs available for MIPS which is - "libssl-dev_1.1.1n-0+deb10u3_mips.deb". But i wanted to install through my script from Ubuntu APT pkg list